# Is the time complexity of this algorithm Θ(n)?

Tags: algorithm, loops, math, time-complexity

I want to find the time complexity of the following algorithm

```
for i=1 to n do
    j=i
    while j<n do
        j=2*j
```

I did my calculations and I found that `T(n) = log(n^n/n!)`.

But the correct answer is supposed to be `T(n) = Θ(n)`.

Was I wrong? Or maybe `log(n^n/n!) = Θ(n)`?

Comment: first impression i think is O(n^2) for loop ist n and the inner while is also n

Comment: @SeekAddo I think if you do some calculations, you'll find out there is a better boundary than n^2

Comment: The inner loop has a runtime of `O(log(n-i))` so my first thought would have been `O(n*log(n))` if you hadn't said the solution is `O(n)`

Comment: @Keiwan: The inner loop has runtime `O(log(n/i))`, not `O(log(n-i))`.

Comment: Oops, yes you're right of course.

Comment: One should not forget that the complexity arises from limiting behaviour, thus, the inner exponentially increasing loop becomes redundant compared to the outer linearly increasing loop (only because the inner loop starts at i though).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is that your formula is equivalent to theirs. You only need to know some math:

[image]

Where first 2 transformations are just basic log properties, and the third is [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

And clearly everyone knows that `n = Θ(n)`

Comment: Plus one for mentioning Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Dali!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative proof could be:

[image: Proof for asked question]

Where [image: substitution description]

Comment: But the inner loop is executed exactly `ceiling{ log(n^n/n!) } - 1` times. No Big-O notations on that

Comment: Where exactly have you seen me subtracting `O(f(n))` and `O(g(n))`? I only simplified OP's expression and told that n is O(n). So you just rewrote my answer a little bit differently.

Comment: In your case you are showing that n log n - n log n + n is = n  which is not true in asymptotic notations and can not be used to compute algorithm complexity.
I don't think that this is rewriting your answer as I don't think that yours is correct. You made good argument about using Stirling formula...

Comment: @kkonrad Meh, he should have written ln n! = n ln n - n + O(ln n) = n ln n - Theta(n) for Stirling's, but close enough.

Comment: @kkonrad That's sufficient because the n ln n terms are exact.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat now I see what you mean. Yup, this would be good to make it accurate. PS never knew that Stirling formula can be expressed that way. Good to know. Thx!

Comment: @kkonrad then you can update your answer, removing the part that states that my answer is wrong. Also if you will read my answer, you will see that there is a link which states exactly what David told: `ln(n!) = n ln n - n + O(ln n)`

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is `Θ(n)`. The exact runtime is `2n`

Check this out:

```
import math

def get_complexity(n):
    counter = 0

    for i in range(1,n):
        j = i
        while j < n:
            j = 2 * j
            counter += 1

    print('n: %16d\niterations:  %6d\n2n:  %14d \n' % (n, counter, 2*n))


for ten in range(1,5):
    get_complexity(10 ** ten)
```

output:

```
n:               10
counter:         16
2n:              20

n:              100
counter:        194
2n:             200

n:             1000
counter:       1990
2n:            2000

n:            10000
counter:      19990
2n:           20000

n:           100000
counter:     199988
2n:          200000
```

Comment: I don't think it will make a big difference but I think you should change `for i in range(1,n)` to `for i in range(1,n+1)`. Cause `range(1, n)` gives `[1, 2, 3, .. n-1]` if I'm not wrong.